# About learning physics

Tags: education

Can I learn physics and engineering even if I have the maths knowledge of a 4th grader? I am familiar with maths but I still struggle with a lot, but I do want to study physics and electronic like electrical engineer.

Comment: I **don't** think this should be closed as opinion-based.  It's a common enough type of question people ask and maybe we should have a useful answer on two on this kind of subject.  I think these type of questions should be exceptions to the opinion-based rule.

Comment: StevenG you are right I want to get by in the maths an physics stack exchange and no matter what I say is not good enough I just want to earn good reputations and experience the fun in this sit but it is hard with a reputation of 6, I am using Khan academy, cosmolearn and YouTube, I want to have fun earning the point and badges there, plus It might help me get a career myself teaching myself, I would love to be a private and online teacher one day.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about career or educational advice.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to learn about physics and engineering with the maths of a 4th grader, in the same sense it is possible to learn about, say, opera without being able to play a musical instrument. In fact it is possible to become passionately interested in opera even though you cannot read music or sing a single note.

However, it will be impossible for you to be an *active participant* in either physics or engineering in the professional sense without an effortless facility with math, since both enterprises are based on it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you've ever heard about Michael Faraday. He is known as one of the most important physicists of all time. Despite never receiving a formal education due to lack of opportunities, his innovative experiments led to the understanding of the relationship between electricity and magnetism. His ideas were later plasmated in the mathematical language by another genius, James Clark Maxwell.

My point is, physics and engineering is not only about math and formulas, but also about understanding crucial concepts and the dynamics between physical systems. While it's true you will need to work to learn the most important mathematics to do calculations, you can also study the physical ideas on the go so you get familiarized with them.

At the end it depends on your goals. If you want to learn physics from a merely conceptual perspective, I think you should be fine knowing nothing beyond middle school algebra. There are plenty of resources on internet to start learning about the topic you may be interested, so I suggest you start slowly with the basics and try to find an online tutor that can help you clear any doubts you may have.

If you want to learn physics and engineering for a professional career, you should surely take some formal education or at the very least have the guidance of an expert in the area who is willing to teach and train you in more advanced concepts such as calculus. My recommendation would be in this case to study up to high school level physics and mathematics and then apply for college.

Answer (score 2):

A knowledge of basic calculus is really needed to do much more than very basic physics in a theoretical sense.

For example the mathematics of Newtonian analysis of two body orbits (like the Earth and the Sun to good accuracy) requires the ability to understand calculus.

Calculus is normally taught at High School level, so that's what you're aiming for, IMO.

I often recommend the Schaum Outline series of books, often available through public libraries.  I learned a great deal from these myself (from the wonderful Dublin Public Libraries :-) ) and they typically have a lot of worked examples and Q&A sections to practice on.

If you want to get an intuitive understanding of physics then you don't necessarily need much mathematics at all.  You will find that you have to take a lot of things "on faith" without some maths skills, but you can learn a lot.

If reading isn't a good way for you to learn have a look on YouTube.  My experience is that there are videos explaining practically everything (maths and physics) up there and if one video doesn't work for you, another will.